# Mathematica: Different histograms with same coordinate system & same bin width specifications

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, width, system, bin, coordinate

I am running a cluster analysis and want to plot some of my results in histograms. To compare one cluster with another I find it useful to use the same coordinate system and same bin width for each histogram. For the plot range I already got a tip:

```
PlotRange/.Options[Histogram[DeleteCases[Flatten[data], {}], 
           PlotRange -> Automatic], PlotRange]
```

Is there a similar approach for the bin width? With my approach you will see that for cluster 3 the bin width is to large as the lowest bar exceeds the coordinate system.

Example:

```
data = {{-1.2056`, -1.46192`, -1.30053`, -2.52879`, -0.99636`, {}},
{-1.73904`, -1.164`, -1.83398`, -0.97505`, {}, {}, -0.503256`,
-0.63802`}, {-0.785963`, -0.711821`, -0.820439`, -1.8699`, -3.9659`,
-1.4456`, -1.67021`, -1.42009`, -2.5644`, -1.45002`, -1.27806`,
-1.66529`, -1.67073`, -3.31102`, -3.38638`}}

Table[
 Histogram[
  DeleteCases[data[[i]], {}], 
  3*Abs[Differences[
      Last[PlotRange /. 
        Options[Histogram[DeleteCases[Flatten[data], {}], 
          PlotRange -> Automatic], PlotRange]]]]/
    Length[DeleteCases[Flatten[data], {}]],
  PlotLabel -> 
   Text[Style["Cluster " <> ToString[i], TextAlignment -> Center]],
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}},
  FrameLabel -> {{"###", None}, {"###", None}},
  PlotRange -> 
   Part[PlotRange /. 
     Options[Histogram[DeleteCases[Flatten[data], {}], 
       PlotRange -> Automatic], PlotRange], 2]
  ], {i, Length[data]}]
```

Comment: As a starting point, and assuming version 8, you could use `HistogramList[Flatten[data]]` to compute bins, and then use that as the second argument to construct the individual histograms.

Comment: If you have a lot of Mathematica questions, there is a separate StackExchange site specifically for [mathematica.se], and it may be worth you while to ask over there. As it stands, this question is on topic for StackOverflow, so it isn't likely to be closed. But, in the future, consider us at the other site.

Comment: Thanks Brett Champion again today! With "FreedmanDiaconis" as binning method I got what I wanted. :)

Comment: Sorry rcollyer for not paying attention. Is there a way to move my post and the previous ones (which also were Mathematica-related questions) to the Mathematica StackExchange sites so that others can benefit from the answers made?

Comment: Because they're on topic here, they won't be moved, at least not for a long while. But, most of the regular users know that questions are still occasionally posted here, so we do check. But, I do encourage you to post on the new site.

Comment: If you got it working, please feel free to answer your own question.